# Issue reinstalling Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I'm trying to reinstall Windows 7 on my laptop, but after I select the language, time, etc. and click "next", nothing happens. I can't do the "repair startup" option or boot into Windows.

Is something wrong with the hard drive? Or is it software problem?

I suspect that there's something wrong with the master boot record; how would I fix this?

I've already looked at [this Wikipedia page on SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T).

I already select "Repair your computer" nothing happen. Just blank screen.

I dont think its the power issue or BIOS setting issue because I already plug-in the power and I already set to default the BIOS setting and no USB is plugged-in.

Comment: Have you tried booting from the Windows 7 DVD > Repair your computer > Use recovery tools that can help fix problems starting windows... > command prompt > type: "format c:"? If not, do that.

That will take care of your formatting question, however it does not resolve your windows 7 installation failure. For that, the issue is usually a power issue, BIOS setting issue, or I/O device issue. Make sure your laptop is plugged in. Ensure Hard drive controller is set to 'compatible' in bios. Turn off wireless adapter and disconnect any USB devices during Windows install. Let me know.

Comment: Even if there was something wrong with the "master boot record" you are reinstalling Windows thus the old "master boot record" would be replaced with a new "master boot record".  This sounds like a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two tests I would try: try installing to a different HD to see if there are issues it (this sounds like a hard drive problem). If that yields no change, try booting with a boot cd like Hiren's Boot and see if the results are the same.

If both yield the same result, I would disconnect all hardware except for keyboard/mouse/monitor. If Windows boots, add each one between reboots to find the piece of hardware that's giving it trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get to the command prompt in windows setup by pressing shift+F10. from there check the log files, there may be a clue there.

Look for log files here: $windows.~bt\Sources\Panther

If you're okay with wiping the disk, type:

```
Diskpart
List Disk
Select Disk #
Clean
Exit
```

(replace # with the number you are wiping, be careful here, take note from what list disk says.)

See Also: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744583(v=ws.10).aspx